# igraph making randomly generated node attribute values?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a code like the following:

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_empty_graph (100) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("a", value = 0) 
V(g)$a <- sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.9))
V(g)$a
```

I want to randomize the node attribute value for "a" with a specific weight. However if I run the program above, all the values for "a" turn to 1 with the occasional exception where the values alternate between 1 and 0. How do I fix this?

Comment: Run your `sample` line without assigning to your vertices. You're generating only 2 numbers, 0 or 1, with a 90% chance each pick will be a `1`. Then you're using those 2 numbers (almost always 1's) to fill in all the attributes.

Comment: Or `sample(c(0, 1), vcount(g), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.9))` to generate a sample of 0 and 1's that is the same length as your number of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use `runif(100, 0, 1)` instead of `sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.9))`, `runif` sample uniform distribution on the interval from min to max.